# Broken Formatting In Notepad

Tags: windows, php, formatting, html, notepad

Often I have problems with formatting in Notepad on Windows XP Home. For example **hidden space** between characters or line breaks.

When I copy text with broken formatting to another place, it all becomes in its true form and messed up - unneeded line breaks for example. Also formatting also sometimes becomes **cluttered** which s confusing when working with HTML/PHP codes.

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots or examples of what you are trying, what the expected result is and what you see instead?

Comment: @slhck: I suspect this might have something to do with the other editor using UNIX LF line breaks, instead of Windows CR + LF.

Comment: @paradroid:  It might also be that @Boris_yo is copying from .PDF files, which also frequently add extra spaces etc.

Comment: a)Some of what you've said sounds like you're opening a text with its own carriage returns, and you've got Word Wrap. b)Another thing, regarding what people have said about windows/unix CRLF/LF Try opening it in wordpad that can read unix style line endings.  c)Other than that perhaps funny high range unicode characters could play a role.   I'd bet on 'b' then 'a'.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No i switched OS.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (freeware) instead of Notepad.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will keep the correct [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: Not quite a solution though.

Comment: Of course not if you changed your OS away from Windows ;)